# Some fonts in plasma are blurry, others are not

Tags: kubuntu, kde, intel-graphics, fonts

So I'm using kubuntu 18.04 on my ThinkPad E480 (UHD 620 as main VGA, RX 550 as secondary) and I cannot seem to get this working. In some applications (like TeXstudio) fonts appear as very blurry. In TeXstudio for example this blurryness disappears when I select a line of text (see example). This problem persists throughout the operating system. For example the shutdown options menu is also blurry and the "Plasma by KDE" text during login is too. I already enabled texture filtering in system settings (enabled, full). I can see the incorrect rendering of the text in screenshots. I have already installed the most recent mesa drivers if that might be an issue. The DPI-setting doesn't change this. I'm pretty much out of ideas unfortunately. I can provide pictures if necessary.

Edit:

[Example 1 from TeXstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb44C.png)

[Second example (closeup picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea6II.png)

Edit2:

So I tried looking for more clues and was not able to resolve this issue. I installed Windows 10 on a Flashdrive to see if the issue persists and I do indeed have similar scaling issues in Windows as I do in Kubuntu.

Comment: Where exactly is "texture filtering in system settings (enabled, full)."?

Comment: @DKBose In the "System settings" application under the "fonts" tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I managed to solve this issue myself. For some background, I also experienced some artifact issues in the terminal, which do not appear after applying the fix anymore either.

So first I created the following folder as it did not exist on my installation yet:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

Then I added a file:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

And pasted this content:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection
```

After rebooting not only the blurry fonts, but also the artifacts were gone.

Comment: How did you come up with this? Also, which specific setting do you think solved this? Was it "TearFree"? I don't have an Intel graphics card (I have NVIDIA) and I'm facing the exact same issues as you mentioned on Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I noticed some tearing in videos and the terminal, like mentioned in my answer, and thought maybe the issues were related. I found a fix on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#troubleshooting and that also helped the blurry fonts. For Nvidia I'm not sure, but you might try the "avoid tearing" section on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for response. What I did to fix this was to set the "Scaling" option in Display Settings to 1, and instead force a font DPI scale of 144. Everything looks nice on my 4k screen now!